# How to fully remove mysql from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, mysql

I have uninstalled mysql from XUbuntu 18.04 doing as follows:

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm /etc/init.d/mysql
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

I did a backup of /etc/init.d/mysql

mysql was removed from CLI, after this. I confirmed this running:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

Questions:

**Why it looks like the service is still working ?**

**What else do I need to do to fully uninstall mysql ?**

This is the output of sudo systemctl status mysql:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service
  Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-04-26 16:02:03 CDT;  24s ago

abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the    mysql database server daemon...
abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[16668]: mysql.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[16668]: mysql.service: Failed at step  EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory
abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 26 16:02:03 dell4 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

I expected it to be:

```
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked when I restarted the system. Thank you. If you put a formal answer I will marked as solved @Kulfy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output it is clear that the MySQL was completely removed and systemctl is unable to load and start that service. Whenever a service is modified or removed, systemctl has to be refreshed. To refresh, run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

But here for some reason, it wasn't refreshed. In such cases, rebooting helps. Rebooting the system refreshes systemctl thoroughly.